# Existence of arbitrarily small invariant neighborhood

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator from a Banach space $M$ to itself.
Suppose that $\rho(A)<1$ where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$.
For any $\varepsilon>0$, does there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of the origin such that $U\subset B(0,\varepsilon)$ and $A(U)\subset U$, where $B(0,\varepsilon)=\{x\in M | \|x\|<\varepsilon\}$?